# How to detect and remove or replace the Number Sign (#) in a filename I'm uploading

Tags: php, mysql, file, str-replace

I'm uploading a group of pictures with the number sign (#) in every filename. I can save the picture in a folder and the filename in my database. But I would like to remove the Number sign before I upload and it saves to my database.

Here's my code but it doesn't work.

```
$i_pic=$_FILES["i_pic"]["name"];
$i_pic=str_replace("#","Item",$i_pic);
```

Thanks for any help from a newbie.

> *Update

Hey guys, thanks for the comments. I'm uploading pictures with 5 input type='file', I'm using loops to upload and save their filenames. I just realized I din't put my counter inside which is supposed to be like this $_FILES["i_pic$i"]["name"]; sorry, my bad. I appreciate all the comments. :)

Comment: You want to remove the "#", or replace it with the word "item"?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$uploaddir = '/var/www/uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . str_replace('#', 'Item',
    basename($_FILES['i_pic']['name']));

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['i_pic']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions (aka regex)

```
$i_pics = preg_replace('/#/', 'Item', $i_pic);
```

If it doesn't help or work, please give some filename exemple.